# Htmlagilitypack do not convert <i> tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I do not convert to HTMLAgilityPack  tags. How can I make the transformation  's values ?

In this way, I want to get an output

> Yayın Tarihi:13.09.2015 --Güncelleme Tarihi:18.09.2015

```html
<ul class="DefaultAspxWebParcasi">
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.e-saglik.gov.tr/belge/1-44068/ozel-saglik-kurum-ve-kuruluslari-tarafindan-saglik-net-.html">
      <i> -Yayın Tarihi</i>
      : 18.09.2015 /
      <i> Güncellenme Tarihi</i>
      : 18.09.2015
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.e-saglik.gov.tr/belge/1-42578/sagliknet-sistemi-2-ve-3-basamak-veri-gonderimi-ile-ilg-.html">
      <i> -Yayın Tarihi</i>
      : 13.08.2015 /
      <i> Güncellenme Tarihi</i>
      : 18.09.2015
  </li>
```

C#code here.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string data = wc.DownloadString(Link());
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(data);
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection icCont2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//ul[@class='DefaultAspxWebParcasi']//li//a");

foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode item in icCont2)
                {
                    string iler = item.SelectSingleNode("//i").InnerHtml.ToString();

                    Console.WriteLine(iler);

                }
```

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: &nbsp;-Yayın Tarihi
&nbsp;-Yayın Tarihi
&nbsp;-Yayın Tarihi
&nbsp;-Yayın Tarihi
&nbsp;-Yayın Tarihi

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to get as blockquote output value in the field

Comment: Yeah I mean if you can explain in English what you want, I'm sure you can find another question that helps you. _"I want to go from X to Y"_ isn't really clear. Do you mean you want to remove `<i></i>` tags from your string, without removing their content, and that you want to decode HTML entities such as `&nbsp;` to their unescaped equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will produce **-Yayın Tarihi : 18.09.2015 / Güncellenme Tarihi : 18.09.2015**. Hope this will be helpful

```
           var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(data);
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection icCont2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//ul[@class='DefaultAspxWebParcasi']//li//a");
            foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode item in icCont2)
            {
                Regex trimmer = new Regex(@"\s\s+");
                var iler = trimmer.Replace(item.InnerText, " ");
                Console.WriteLine(iler);
            }
```